Usar MDBBootstrap en un proyecto Angular 17 da error No directive found with exportAs mdbCollapse
por favor merezco su ayuda, acabo de crear un proyecto con Angular 17 y estoy tratando de utilizar MDBBootstrap en una aplicacion angular; copie el ejemplo que tienen un su portal:
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <button
      class="navbar-toggler"
      type="button"
      (click)="togglerFirstExample.toggle()"
      aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-label="Toggle navigation"
    >
      <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </button>
    <div
      class="collapse navbar-collapse"
      id="navbarTogglerDemo01"
      mdbCollapse
      #togglerFirstExample="mdbCollapse"
    >
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hidden brand</a>
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true"
            >Disabled</a
          >
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex input-group w-auto">
        <input
          type="search"
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Type query"
          aria-label="Search"
        />
        <button
          class="btn btn-outline-primary"
          type="button"
          data-mdb-ripple-color="dark"
        >
          Search
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

El problema que tengo es que me da un error y no se como solucionarlo

No directive found with exportAs mdbCollapse


Estuve tratando de buscar la documentación para usar en un proyecto standalone, pero en cada lugar que busco entiendo que debo importar en ngModule.

Realmente la pregunta debería ser “como importar módulos en el componente?” Lo cual solamente es agregando imports: [AQUI VAN LOS MODULOS] dentro de @Component o si piensas (como yo) que esto complica las cosas puedes crear un proyecto nuevo (si es que no tienes más hecho aún) y agregar --no-standalone al momento de crearlo. No se si exista alguna forma de implementar los módulos y reconfigurar todo eso en Angular 17, pero si tienes mucho hecho pues habrá que investigar

Tienes razón, creo que por el momento lo más práctico será crear un proyecto que no sea standalone, en realidad si trate con los imports pero no pude hacerlo.
